# Django integration tests

Tags: python-3.x, django, integration-testing

For the first time faced with the task of **integration** tests in django.

Found on the Internet only a couple of small articles on this topic.

Example: There are three different servers that communicate with each other. What tools can be used to write tests for such a system? It turns out that I need to run two servers at the same time, create databases there and then emit work (accessing the API) between them.

Can you please tell me what tools can be used to implement such tests?

Or am I misunderstanding the meaning of "integration test" and as a result I just have to write tests for my api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the context there could be different interpretations what an integration should be. Generally, you can say that you have an integration test when you are testing that multiple parts of your application working correctly together.

If you want to write integration tests for your api, create some data in your database, use the Django's Testclient to access your api and compare your results of you api response to your expected result. Of course you should also check authentication, authorization, data not found and so on.

Even though you should write integration tests, I recommend that you write at least one unit test regarding the get_queryset method if you are using CBVs.

In order to easily prepolulate your database, you could use FactoryBoy: https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

If you use pure Django, check out their guide on testing: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/tools/

If you use Django Rest Framework check out their testing guide regarding their testclient: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/